# How to make a JS MVC app (backbone/knockout/angular) "preloadable" by the server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, model-view-controller, knockout.js

Imagine that I have a SPA built with a JS MVC framework/library with the model "user" and a view which displays a list of users.
Normally, I would get my users list from my server (via a RESTful API or whatever), instantiate my models with that list, and my view would be subsequently rendered, showing the user list. This is a very simple case.

Now, imagine that I have 1 million users. It would be slow to send over the wire a JSON with so much data, and make a client (which could be, let's say, an android phone) parse it, build up a model and render a one million rows html table.

But let's say that my users list can't be modified by the SPA. Let's say that it is modified by another page (like an "user management" page). In that case, the SPA is "read only". It has some cool stuff like filtering on the list, so it makes sense to use an MVC, but the "user" model is read-only in this SPA.

In that case, a solution for that "million users" problem would be to "preload" the client SPA server-side. It means that a "model" user with a million entries is instantiated server-side, a view with a million entries html table is rendered server-side. Then we send the model and the view to the client.
We will "preload" this app only when it is modified by the "user management" page. Apart from that, it will always be the same SPA which is sent to the clients, so no need to "preload" it at each client's request, we can cache it.

Now, I understand that server-side template rendering is doable, but **I don't know how to make the app "interactive" once it's on the client's side**.

By interactive I mean that it would work exactly as if I had created an empty SPA with an empty view, then loaded and rendered the one million users client-side.

Comment: you will do paging, page for 20...30. you don't download json for 1 million users

Comment: of course, the example I gave here is simplified in order to explain it without writing three pages, if it was just about a user list, I would paginate. The real app manages a lot of models with a lot of contents, but the problem is the same : too much work for the client

Comment: @Rayjax if it's too much work to compute by the client, it's probably too much work to display by the client. Decrease the amount of data that's being loaded by the client. Send the page with a server encoded json object, and initialize your viewmodel in the SPA. If your client is not powerful enough to process and render that much data, it's not going to perform well enough to use it anyway.

Comment: @xdumaine what you suggest, if I got it well, is rendering the view server-side, sending the json with the data + the rendered view to the client, then tell the client to display the already rendered view and to create its model from the json ? that would avoid the client-side rendering but it would keep the huge json parsing+model creation client-side.

I was thinking of sending rendered views + configured models over the wire, but maybe it's not doable

Comment: @Rayjax think about what happens when you build up your client side viewmodels with data binding - you're loading data into an in-memory javascript object that performs updates and actions on events, or events on updates or actions. You want to pre-load that in memory object on the server? How would you send that to the client? Attach events? That needs to be done on the client.

Comment: @xdumaine I know that I can't send already existing models and bindings over the wire, but I was thinking about building a "configuration" js script server-side, based on the json, and inject this js script into the client instead of JSON. This way, the client only has to execute that js script, which will create models and bindings, instead of having to parse the json and then create the models and bindings

Comment: @Rayjax Encoding the objects on the page as javascript or as json, then parsing the json into a javascript would both work, and would have a negligible difference (dozens of milliseconds tops) at any reasonable amount of data. Again, if it's so much data that it takes too long to parse json, or load javascript objects, it's not going to perform well anyway, in which case you should decrease your data size.

Comment: @xdumaine unfortunately decreasing data size is not an option. I have huge amounts of data and often clients are using iphones or androids (even BBs). So I have to compel with low performance + disconnected scenarios, which means that I have to move all the possible logic to the server, and send everything at first loading because then connection could be unavailable

Comment: @xdumaine anyway, what you suggested seems viable. Would you kindly make an answer out of that ?

Comment: @xdumaine don't you think that rendr by Airbnb would fit the problem ? If I got it well, it's all about sharing views + model between server and client

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49545/discussion-between-rayjax-and-xdumaine)